# Need help in Twitter api (Abraham"s TwitterOAuth: Could Not Authenticate You)

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using Abraham"s TwitterOauth library to build an application that connects with Twitter and reads the timeline.

It would be great if Abraham Williams himself would answer my question but anyone that is familiar with the library is more than welcome to respond.
I am using the whole TwitterOauth library including the files that get called in this order: redirect.php, callback.php, index.php.

It sort of works: the user is redirected to twitter log in to give rights to the app and I can get the tokens.
The files redirect.php, callback.php, index.php are being called in this order. The problem is in index.php when I do a:

```
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

$content contains [error]=>could not authenticate you.
I saw a question about this already saying that the cause for this error is overwriting the access token. Now I am using all the files as they are available from download with the library. I didn't modify anything. 
Where in these files could be the overwriting of the access token?

I printed the final access token in callback.php and it showes the same token each time and my twitter user ID and my twitter user name wich means it sort of works. I don't know where is the problem. I don't modify anything in the abraham library files.

Comment: did you change the CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, and OAUTH_CALLBACK in config.php?

Comment: yes i did. As I said in the question, it works partially. If i print the access_token I can see my twitter user ID and twitter user name.

Comment: Does the library work for you out of the box, without any modifications? If you modified something can you tell me about it?

Comment: I believe I have must have an older version of the toolchain.  Could you provide me with a link to the exact version you are using?

Comment: Try starting with a fresh copy of the TwitterOAuth code just to make sure something didn't get changed on accident.

Comment: BUSTER: i got the library from https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth latest version

ABRAHAM: i tried with a fresh copy and i get the same "Cannot authenticate with OAuth". I do make one minor modification. I don't have hash_hmac on my hosting so I added a few small files with its implementation and in OAuth.php, at the beginning I do: require 'hash_hmac.php'; Could this be the problem that something is not encoded right? I can see my username if I print the $access_token, and the access token is the same all the time. Does this mean that hash_hmac is not the problem?

Comment: I tried to switch to PLAIN_TEXT signature to see if it works and the response is not 200 so i get "Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later" in redirect.php. And the curl response is: "Failed to validate oauth signature and token". I think I got it right. I'm not sure what I can do. Maybe I should try replace the hash_hmac implementation with another one.

Comment: ABRAHAM: i uploaded the small files I add with hash_hmac implementation here: http://summifyx.octopis.com/twitter2.zip It just contains the twitteroauth directory. You would have to explicitly call this hash_hmac function as it detects if there is already one. See if it works for you. When you have time of course. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

at the moment i'm using [this one](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-async-documentation.html) it's quite simple.
If you want i can post my working example.